# Temporarily disable scrolling with mousewheel.js

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I have a horizontally scrolling website. Iam using mousewheel.js to scroll horizontally with the mousewheel (or up and down). I am using a snippet from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) like so:

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 5);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
```

As I scroll down, the browser interprets it as a right scroll. This works great.

I need to be able to temporarily disable this behavior. For instance, I have panel that overlays the site with a gallery. While that panel is open, I want to disable the scrolling like so:

```
$("a.gal").on("click", function(){
    $("#galPanel").addClass("open");
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When we exit the panel, I want to reinitiate the mousewheel plugin.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

UPDATE: I found a working solution, but am unsure if this is the best way of going about it:

```
$("#galPanel").bind("mousewheel", function() {
       return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already used `.on()`, go with **`.on()`** and **`.off()`** for mousewheel event.

```
$("body").on('mousewheel', function(){
// ToDos
});

$("a.gal").on("click", function(){
    $("#galPanel").addClass("open");
    $("body").off('mousewheel', false);
});
```

I'm not sure how to get it working in your code.  But this simple, like **switch** (*ON and OFF*).

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help: You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#galPanel').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta){
        event.preventDefault(); // Or return false
});
```